# URI.resolve() does not support the full spectrum of allowed file name characters

Tags: java, uri

I used to use a URI element for representing the base folder and use URI.resolve(filename) to get the URI to the actually file I would like to write to disk.

Now I come along that for apparent reasons the resolve method does not support many characters that the OS supports for file names and those have to be encoded using %HEX.

Since I am not aware of that limitation and how far the encoding really goes. Often this is used in parameter values and I can barely come up with a situation I see encoding in the path.

So is it save to assume that using URI.resolve(URLEncoder.encode(filename)) does the trick? Are there any better alternatives or edge cases I should know about?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually URI.create(en) which fails, for example using "!@#$%^&()" (which is a valid if a very strange filename) throws `IllegalArgumentException: Malformed escape pair at index 4`
As for `URLEncoder.encode(filename)` - It is deprecated and `URLEncoder.encode(filename, encoding)` should be used instead.
From my experience, filename URI resolution is best handled by `new File(f).toURI()` as for a given abstract pathname f, it is guaranteed that:

> new File(f.toURI()).equals( f.getAbsoluteFile())

Comment: Thanks. So basically for my example it is like: uri.resolve(...) -> new File(new File(uri), filename).toURI() which is adviced.

Comment: Yes, that will also work when uri denotes the parent

Comment: Worked as intended. Is there a problem if I address a remote file using a non-filesystem related URI?

Comment: If I have for example a remote network resource and add a file to it so it does not start with file:// but ftp:// for instance.

Comment: URIs generated from Files will always have "file" as URI schema. For other schemas such as FTP, you should use URLEncoder.encode(str, encoding)

Comment: Ok thanks again. I will keep an eye on this since I also support jar files (placing files in an existing file) so it would be a third case then. Ok thanks.